# C# Get Request (API) - How to Callback? (Delegate?)

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, request, http-get

I think for what I want to do, I need some kind of callback/delegate. For now Is spend about 8 hours reading stuff about those callbacks an watched some youtube videos, but still I don't fully understand how they work. (Newer used callbacks in any language till now.)

On button-click I call the function:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetRequest("http://192.168.68.127/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=MediaClip", "root", "root");
}
```

Here is the function which is use to get the result of the request:

```
public static async void GetRequest(string url, string user, string pass)
{
    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass) })
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                        string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        // --- Do different stuff with "mycontent", depending which button was clicked ---
                        // --- Insert function here ?! ---
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is, how can I tell "GetRequest(string url, string user, string pass)" to execute a specific function on the place I need it?
I think I would need sth. like:

```
GetRequest(string url, string user, string pass, function())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `async-await` you don't need use a "callbacks"

Change your method to return "awaitable" content.

```
public static async Task<string> GetRequest(string url, 
                                            string user, 
                                            string pass)
{
    var credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass);
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials })
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Notice return type of the method `Task<string>`

Then use it anywhere you want

```
string content = await GetRequest("url", "admin", "admin");
// Do staff with content
```

Comment: This exact code throws: `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.`

Comment: @AlexG - not exact code, you are missing `async` keyword in your method declaration ;)

Comment: my method is `private static async Task<string> HttpGet(int type = 0) {}` with `return await client.GetStringAsync(uri);` and I call it with `string response = await HttpGet();`

Comment: http://zuga.net/articles/cs-error-CS4033-the-await-operator-can-only-be-used-within-an-async-method/

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a `delegate`, which defines the signature of the methods
   belong to the `delegate`. In this case: return value `void` and no
   parameters:

`public delegate void YourDelegate();`

2. Define the callback function which should be used for `GetRequest`:

`public void CallbackFunction() {...}`

3. Define a parameter in the `GetRequest` method to use the callback function:

`public void GetRequest(string url, string user, string pass, YourDelegate callback) {...}`

4. Invoke the callback in `GetRequest`:

`callback.Invoke()`;

5. Example for executing `GetRequest`:

`GetRequest("http://192.168.68.127/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=MediaClip", "root", "root", CallbackFunction);`